# Conga Template - Access Contact Fields from Event

Tags: conga

I am currently trying to rebuild a Conga Solution on Event to generate a meeting report which simply puts outcomes of meeting and other information for distribution to management for key accounts. The original was running via Salesforce Reports but we cannot use this solution in lightning.

I have everything working with the exception of listing the contacts that were on the meeting, the fields are not showing in the template builder.

Here is the query:

[image: Event-Contact query]

Here's what this looks like when I'm in the template builder, I can only see a relationship column, but none of the corresponding fields from the query:

[image: Template Builder]

Not sure what I'm missing here, anyone have some insight? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, but I figured it out! Wrong relationship and going through the query builder doesn't expose the correct relationship, not enough paying attention on my part, but got it figured out! Here's the query that I used to pull this information:

```
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Title
    FROM Contact WHERE Id IN( select RelationId FROM EventWhoRelation WHERE 
    EventId = '{pv0}' AND Type='Contact')
```

If you're pulling Leads and Contacts you would not need the Type='Contact', or just leads using Type='Lead', so adjust accordingly.